# How can I take a mean of the various columns in a dataframe on the basis of timestamps to make a plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a diurnal curve, which shows the data for the specified duration. Using the code below, I was able to plot a curve (snapshot below) that showed the mean of the data for the specified time duration for the months in the duration.

Is there a way in which I could plot a curve that would average out the data in the desired column for the specified time for all months eg-'01:00:00' to '01:00:00', '02:00:00' to '02:00:00' etc for all the 3 months in the data frame below, and then plot it in a single line instead of having separate lines for different months?

[Diurnal plot snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvv6W.png)

I am putting in a sample data frame for the sake of the code(original data frame has thousands of rows and a few columns)-

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as pt
from matplotlib import dates as d
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
dataframe = pd.DataFrame( 
    columns = ['From Date',   'NO',          'NO2',       'NOx',    'CO',           'Ozone'],           
    data = [
        ['2018-12-30 00:00:00', 5.856666,    39.208341,   28.97,   331.280881,  19.778900],
        ['2018-12-30 01:00:00', 4.050059,    16.262145,   13.53,   454.031703,  25.075286],
        ['2018-12-30 02:00:00', 4.057806,    15.293990,   12.96,   466.502681,  24.825294],
        ['2018-12-30 03:00:00', 3.835476,    13.526193,   11.71,   446.526784,  25.033312],
        ['2018-12-30 04:00:00', 4.230690,    11.251531,   10.70,   355.638469,  25.748796],
        ['2020-01-01 00:00:00',    1,            2,        6.91,    4,             5],
        ['2020-01-01 01:00:00',            5,           10,        7.37,    13.2,          9],
        ['2020-01-01 02:00:00',            4,           13,        8.28,    4,             4],
        ['2020-01-01 03:00:00',            3,           9,         8.57,    3,             5],
        ['2020-01-01 04:00:00',            2,           4,         9.12,    4,             6],
        ['2020-02-01 00:00:00',            2,            3,        6,    8,             9],
        ['2020-02-01 01:00:00',            5,           10,        7.37,    10.2,          8],
        ['2020-02-01 02:00:00',            4,           13,        8.28,    2,             5],
        ['2020-02-01 03:00:00',            3,           9,         8.57,    7,             3],
        ['2020-02-01 04:00:00',            2,           4,         9.12,    2,             2]        
    ]
)
dataframe['From Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['From Date'])
dataframe = dataframe.set_index('From Date')
dataframe.replace('NoData', np.nan, inplace= True)
dataframe['Ozone']=dataframe['Ozone'].astype(float)
dataframe['NOx']=dataframe['NOx'].astype(float)
dataframe['NO']=dataframe['NO'].astype(float)
dataframe['NO2']=dataframe['NO2'].astype(float)
dataframe['Month'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m"))
dataframe['Time'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"))
# Creates subplots based on the number of months
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12,6))
                       
for month in dataframe['Month'].unique():
                       
    df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Month'] == month]
    df = df.groupby('Time').describe()
    ax.plot(df.index, df['NO2']['mean'], linewidth=6.0, label=month)
    ax.legend()
    ticks = ax.get_xticks()
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(
        d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 5))
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(
        d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 25), minor=True)
    ax.set_title("NO2 conc")  # <--------------
    ax.set_xlabel("Time")  # <--------------
    ax.set_ylabel("Concn in ppb")# <--------------
ax.plot(df.index, df['NO2']['75%'], color='g')
ax.plot(df.index, df["NO2"]['25%'], color='r')
ax.fill_between(df.index, df["NO2"]['mean'], df["NO2"]['75%'], alpha=.5, facecolor='y')
ax.fill_between(df.index, df["NO2"]['mean'], df["NO2"]['25%'], alpha=.5, facecolor='r')    
fig.tight_layout(pad=2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pd.Grouper

```
dataframe.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'From Date', freq = '3h'))['NO','NO2'].mean()
```

I used 3 hour frequency but there are more options.
check pd.Grouper.

Comment: I am able to get an average, but it's messing up the data.  I want an average of the data from '01:00'-'01:00' of each day, data of 02:00-02:00(next day), is this possible?